# interning confusion

Tags: c#, string

My understanding is that literals are automatically interend. Let's take below code example.

```
 string s = "x" + "y" + "z";  
 Console.WriteLine(String.IsInterned(s) ?? "Not Interned");  

 string ss = new string(new char[] { 'x', 'y', 'z' });  
 Console.WriteLine(String.IsInterned(ss) ?? "Not Interned");  

 string sss = new string(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' });  
 Console.WriteLine(String.IsInterned(sss) ?? "Not Interned");
```

The output it as follows.

> xyz
>      xyz
>      Not Interned

So from code example below strings s and ss proves that literals are automatically interened. I am not sure why same is not the case for string sss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interning is initially done by the compiler. Due to constant folding, it collapses `"x" + "y" + "z"` into a single string instance `"xyz"`, which is interned because it's a string literal.

Then when you create the second string instance at runtime, it equals the interned compile-time instance (but it's still a different instance), so `IsInterned` can find that string and return it. You never explicitly interned a string value of `"abc"` and also never specified it as string literal in any way. That's why it's not interned by default.

Answer (score 4):

You're misunderstanding `IsInterned`.

`IsInterned()` checks whether the pool has a string with the same value that you pass it; it does not check whether the instance you passed is itself interned.

`"x" + "y" + "z"` is interned, so `String.IsInterned(ss)` will return that instance.

Comment: Let's forget about variable ss. Runtime did interened variable s (that's why its returning xyz). Why we are not getting same response for sss.I expect to get back abc

Comment: No-one ever interned `"abc"`.  String **literals** are interned

Comment: If you were to compile these separately, you'd get `xyz`, `Not Interned`, and `Not Interned`.  If you were to change `s` to `"abc"`, then `abc` would be interned, but `xyz` would not.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the answers of Wormbo & SLaks. The following unit test gives an idea of what happens with the equality comparision.

```
[Test]
public void StringInterningTests()
{
    string a = "Hello";
    string stringFromCharArray = new string(new char[] {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});

    Assert.IsTrue("Hello" == a);
    Assert.IsTrue(stringFromCharArray == "Hello");
    Assert.IsTrue(new String(new char[]{'H','e','l','l','o'}) == stringFromCharArray);
}
```